# Set of $\delta$s in $\epsilon-\delta.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I've started learning real analysis in February of this year. By now, I'm able to prove most things in Calculus AB and BC from first principles but not much else. Hence, I am not too knowledgeable about the subject. I've recently tried proving harder things with just this knowledge. While writing these proofs, I often end up using the following object and I wish to know if there is a name for and/or there is any literature on it.

The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit states that, if for every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
where $L$ is some real number then
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L.$$
Is there any name for the set of all $\delta$'s that work for some partiular $\epsilon$? Let $\epsilon_I>0$ be a constant. Then, is there a name for the set
$$\Delta_{\epsilon_I}=\{\delta\mid 0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon_I\}.$$

---

Here's the proof in which I used this set. It is a long one in my opinion. The theorem is:
If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b],$ then the Darboux integral $\int_a^b f$ is defined.

Lemma 1: If 
$$G(r)=\sup\{f(x)\mid x \in [a,r]\}$$ 
where $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ (with $a<b$) and $\text{Dom}(G)=(a,b),$ then 
$$\lim_{r \to a^+} G(r)=f(a),$$
Proof: Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ we know that 
$$\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x)=f(a).$$
That is, for every $\epsilon>0,$ there must exist a $\delta_3$ such that 
$$0\le x-a<\delta_3 \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$
Rewriting the above yields 
$$x \in [a,a+\delta_3) \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$
This will come in handy shortly. Let $\epsilon>0,$ then we need to show that there exists a $\delta_4$ such that 
$$r \in (a,a+\delta_4) \implies |G(r)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$
The above is just the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition written differently. Hence, if we choose $\delta_3=\delta_4,$ then we'll have $r\in (a,a+\delta_3)$ and $x \in [a, a+\delta_3).$ By definition, we have 
$$G(r)=\sup\{f(x)\mid x \in [a,r]\}.$$
By the extreme value theorem, there must exist some $e\in [a,r]$ such that $f(e)=G(r).$ However, we know that 
$$G(r)=f(e)\in \{f(x)\mid x \in [a,r]\}.$$
Since $e\in [a,r]\subset [a,a+\delta_3),$ it must be the case that 
$$x \in [a,a+\delta_3) \implies |f(e)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$
Consequently, 
$$r\in (a,a+\delta_3) \implies |G(r)-f(a)|=|f(e)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$$
Hence, 
$$\lim_{r \to a^+} G(r)=f(a).$$
$\square$

Corollary 1: If 
$$g(r)=\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in [a,r]\}$$
with $a<b$ and $\text{Dom}(g)=(a,b),$ then 
$$\lim_{r\to a^+}g(r)=f(a).$$
Proof: Consider the function $-f(x).$ Define 
$$G_1(r)=\sup\{-f(x)\mid x\in [a,r]\}$$
where $\text{Dom}(G_1)=(a,b).$ We know from lemma 1 that 
$$\lim_{r\to a^+} G_1(r)=-f(a).$$
It can be easily seen that 
$$G_1(r)=-g(r)$$
for all $r\in (a,b).$ Consequently, 
$$\lim_{r\to a^+} G_1(r)=-f(a)=\lim_{r\to a^+} -g(r)=-\lim_{r\to a^+}g(r).$$
Rearranging yields 
$$\lim_{r\to a^+} g(r)=f(a).$$
$\square$

Lemma 2: If 
$$G_2(r)=\sup\{f(x)\mid x\in[r,b]\}$$
where $a<b$ and $\text{Dom}(G_2)=(a,b),$ then 
$$\lim_{r\to b^-} G_2(r)=f(b).$$
Proof: Consider the function $f(-x+a+b)=f_1(x).$ It can be proven that $f_1$ is continuous. We know that $f_1(a+b-x)=f(x).$ Additionally, we also know that 
$$x\in [r,b] \implies a+b-x\in [a,a+b-r].$$
Hence, we deduce that 
$$G_2(r)=\sup\{f(x)\mid x\in[r,b]\}=\sup\{f_1(a+b-x)\mid a+b-x\in [a,a+b-r]\}. $$
Then, define 
$$G_3(a+b-r)=\sup\{f_1(a+b-x)\mid a+b-x\in [a,a+b-r]\}. $$ 
Letting $u=a+b-r$ and $v=a+b-x$ yields
$$G_3(u)=\sup\{f_1(v)\mid v\in [a,u]\}.$$
Taking the limit as $r\to b^-$ yields 
$$\lim_{r\to b^-} G_3(a+b-r)=\lim_{a+b-r\to a^+} G_3(a+b-r)=\lim_{u\to a^+} G_3(u).$$
Finally, applying lemma 1 to the last expression and un-doing some substitutions gives us 
$$\lim_{u \to a^+} G_3(u)=f_1(a)=f(-a+a+b)=f(b).$$
However, remember that $G_3(a+b-r)=G_2(r).$ Consequently, 
$$\lim_{r\to b^-} G_3(a+b-r)=\lim_{r\to b^-} G_2(r)=f(b).$$
$\square$

Corollary 2: If 
$$g_1(r)=\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in [r,b]\}$$
where $a<b$ and $\text{Dom}(g_1)=(a,b),$ then 
$$\lim_{r \to b^-} g_1(r)=f(b).$$
Proof: Consider the function $-f(x).$ Define
$$G_4(r)=\sup\{-f(x)\mid x\in [r,b]\}$$
where $\text{Dom}(G_4)=(a,b).$ Applying the result from lemma 2, we get 
$$\lim_{r\to b^-} G_4(r)=-f(b).$$
As was done in corollary 1, it can be deduced that 
$$g_1(r)=-G_4(r)$$
for all $r\in (a,b).$ Consequently, 
$$\lim_{r\to b^-} g_1(r)=\lim_{r\to b^-} -G_4(r)=-(-f(b))=f(b).$$
$\square$

With these results in hand, we can now proceed.  Let $r_0=a$ and define 
$$H_i(r)=\sup\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_i,r]\},$$
$$h_i(r)=\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_i,r]\}$$
where $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ such that $r_i<b$ and $\text{Dom}(H_i),\text{Dom}(h_i)=(r_i,b).$ Given this, we will now create a procedure to find $r_{i+1}.$ Any $r_k$s found in this manner will be called "optimal $r_k$s for $\epsilon_I$." We will define $\epsilon_I$ in a minute. We know from lemma 1 and corollary 1 that 
$$\lim_{r\to r_i^+}(H_i(r)-h_i(r))=0.$$
Consequently, for every $\epsilon_0>0,$ there must exist a $\delta_i$ such that 
$$0<r-r_i<\delta_i\implies |H_i(r)-h_i(r)|<\epsilon_0.$$
Let $\epsilon_I>0$ and let it be a constant. Then, define 
$$_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}=\{\delta_i \mid 0<r-r_i<\delta_i\implies |H_i(r)-h_i(r)|<\epsilon_I\}.$$
Next, let $0<c<1$ be a constant. Then, define 
$$\delta_{oi}=c\cdot \sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}.$$
Now, we know that 
$$0<r-r_i<\delta_{oi} \implies r\in (r_i,r_i+\delta_{oi})\implies  |H_i(r)-h_i(r)|<\epsilon_I.$$
Finally, choose $r_{i+1}=r_i+c\cdot \delta_{oi}.$ Note that the same $c$ must be used to find out every $r_{k}.$

Now, let's say that this procedure (that is, all $r_i$s are optimal for $\epsilon_I$) is performed and we find that $r_{i+1}=r_{i}+c\cdot \delta_{oi}\ge b$ for some positive integer $i.$ In that case, simply choose $r_{i+1}=b$ and terminate the process. Our goal is to prove that this process always terminates for some $i+1.$

Lemma 3: $r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}\le r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}$ for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}.$
Proof: For all $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that $\delta_1<\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}$ and $\delta_2<\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\},$ we know that
$$0<r_1-r_i<\delta_1\implies H_i(r_1)-h_i(r_1)<\epsilon_I,$$
$$0<r_2-r_{i+1}<\delta_2\implies H_{i+1}(r_2)-h_{i+1}(r_2)<\epsilon_I.$$
The absolute value signs aren't needed on the right side of $\implies$ here for obvious reasons. Rewriting this yields 
$$r_1\in (r_i,r_i+\delta_1) \implies H_i(r_1)-h_i(r_1)<\epsilon_I,$$
$$r_2\in (r_{i+1},r_{i+1}+\delta_2) \implies H_{i+1}(r_2)-h_{i+1}(r_2)<\epsilon_I.$$
Let's focus on the first statement above. Note that 
$$r_1' \in (r_i+\delta_1,r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\})\implies  H_i(r_1')-h_i(r_1')<\epsilon_I$$
since there must exist a $\delta_1'$ such that $r_1'<r_i+\delta_1'.$ Because of this, we can just rewrite the two statements as follows:
$$r_1\in (r_i,r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}) \implies H_i(r_1)-h_i(r_1)<\epsilon_I,$$
$$r_2\in (r_{i+1},r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}) \implies H_{i+1}(r_2)-h_{i+1}(r_2)<\epsilon_I.$$
Remember that 
$$H_i(r_1)=\sup\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_i,r_1]\},$$
$$h_i(r_1)=\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_i,r_1]\},$$
$$H_{i+1}(r_2)=\sup\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_{i+1},r_2]\},$$
$$h_{i+1}(r_2)=\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_{i+1},r_2]\}.$$
Next, assume that 
$$r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}> r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}.$$
We know that $r_{i+1}>r_i.$ Consequently, 
$$(r_{i+1},r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\})\subset (r_i,r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}).$$
We want
$$ H_i(r_1')-h_i(r_1')<\epsilon_I,$$
$$H_{i+1}(r_2)-h_{i+1}(r_2)<\epsilon_I.$$
Hence, we can let $r_1'\in (r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\},r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\})$ to satisfy the first statement. Consequently,
$$[r_{i+1},r_2]\subset [r_i,r_1']$$ 
for any $r_2\in (r_{i+1},r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}).$ By definition (of $\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}$), no other value of $r_2$ will satisfy the second statement above. Hence, it follows from our assumption that 
$$H_{i+1}(r_2)-h_{i+1}(r_2)\le H_i(r_1')-h_i(r_1').$$
But now let's see what happens if we let $r_2'=r_1'.$ It is still the case that 
$$[r_{i+1},r_1']\subset [r_i,r_1']$$
Hence, 
$$H_{i+1}(r_2')-h_{i+1}(r_2')\le H_i(r_1')-h_i(r_1').$$
However, we know that 
$$H_{i+1}(r_2')-h_{i+1}(r_2')\le H_i(r_1')-h_i(r_1')<\epsilon_I.$$
This is a contradiction since $r_2'\not \in (r_{i+1},r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}).$ Herefore, we can conclude that 
$$r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}\not > r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}.$$
Consequently,
$$r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}\le  r_{i+1}+\sup\{_{i+1}\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}$$
as desired.
$\square$

Next, assume that there always exists an $r_i$ such that $r_{i+1}-r_i<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0.$
Corollary 3: It follows from the above assumption that there must always be more than $n+1$ intervals after the procedure for any positive integer $n.$
Proof: If, at the end of this process, we had $n+1$ intervals, then it follows that there must be an $r_k$ such that $r_{k+1}-r_k\ge r_{i+1}-r_i$ for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}.$ However, this contradicts our assumption that $r_{i+1}-r_i<\epsilon$ for some $i.$ Hence, it follows from our assumption that there must be more than $n+1$ (for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$) intervals after the entire process.

Next, define 
$$\mathbb{o}=\{r_i\mid i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\}.$$
By construction, we know that $\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}\le b.$ Additionally, since $c,\delta_{oi}>0,$ it must be the case that $r_{i+1}=r_i+c\cdot \delta_{oi}>r_i.$ Consequently, $\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}\not\in \mathbb{o}.$

Lemma 4: $r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}\le \sup\{\mathbb{o}\}$ for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}.$
Proof: Assume that existed an $i$ such that $r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}> \sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$ It then follows from lemma 3 that for all $k\ge i,$ we must have 
$$r_k+\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}\ge r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}>\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$$ 
It follows that 
$$0<r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}-\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}\le r_k+\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}-\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$$
Now, let 
$$z=r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}-\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$$
Hence, 
$$0<z\le r_k+\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}-\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$$
Since $r_k<\sup\{\mathbb{o}\},$ we get 
$$0<z\le r_k+\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}-\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}<\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}+\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}-\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}=\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}.$$
Note that since $z$ is a positive constant, we have found a lower bound for $\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}.$ That is, we have established 
$$0<z<\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}$$
for any $k\ge i.$ This, in turn, means that 
$$0<zc^2<c^2\cdot \sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}.$$
By definition, we know that there must be an $r_k$ arbitrarily close to (but not equal to) $\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$ Pick an $r_k$ with the property that 
$$\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}-r_k<zc^2.$$

We know that $r_{k+1}=r_k+c^2\cdot\sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}.$ Consequently,
$$\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}-r_{k+1}=\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}-r_k-c^2\cdot \sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}<zc^2-c^2\cdot \sup\{_k\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}<0.$$
Therefore, we have 
$$\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}-r_{k+1}<0.$$
Consequently, 
$$\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}<r_{k+1}.$$
This is clearly a contradiction. This means that our assumption was incorrect. Hence, 
$$r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}\le \sup\{\mathbb{o}\}$$
for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}.$
$\square$

Using the thought process from lemma 3, we know that 
$$r_3\in (r_i,r_i+\sup\{_i\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}) \implies H_i(r_3)-h_i(r_3)<\epsilon_I.$$
Additionally, from lemma 4, we know that whatever $r_3$ might be, it has to be the case that 
$$r_3<\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$$
Equivalently, we could say that 
$$H_i(\sup\{\mathbb{o}\})-h_i(\sup\{\mathbb{o}\})=\sup\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_i,\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}]\}-\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in [r_i,\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}]\}\not< \epsilon_I$$
for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}.$ However, we know that there must always be an $r_i$ arbitrarily close to $\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}.$ The fact that no $r_i$ satisfies this means that lemma 2 and corollary 2 are violated. To see how, consider the function $j(x)$ with the property that 
$$j(x)=f(x)$$
when $x\in [a,\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}].$ Also consider the function 
$$J(r_i)=\sup\{j(x)\mid x\in [r_i,\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}]\}-\inf\{j(x)\mid x\in [r_i,\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}]\}.$$
By lemma 2 and corollary 2, we must have 
$$\lim_{r_i\to \sup\{\mathbb{o}\}^-} J(r_i)=0.$$
However, we just showed that no matter how close $r_i$ gets to $\sup\{\mathbb{o}\}$, $J(r_i)-0$ doesn't go below $\epsilon_I.$ This is a contradiction. Consequently, our process always guarentees $n+1$ intervals for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}.$ This means that our process always gives us a partition $\mathcal{R}$ such that 
$$a=r_0<r_1<...<r_n<r_{n+1}=b.$$
Additionally, this partition also has the property that 
$$H_i(r_{i+1})-h_i(r_{i+1})<\epsilon_I$$ 
for any $0\le i<n+1.$ At last, we define 
$$u(f,\mathcal{R})=\sum_{i=0}^n H_i(r_{i+1})(r_{i+1}-r_i),$$
$$l(f,\mathcal{R})=\sum_{i=0}^n h_i(r_{i+1})(r_{i+1}-r_i).$$
Keep in mind that $H_i,h_i$ are functions and $H_i(r_{i+1}),h_i(r_{i+1})$ specific values that these functions take on. Subtracting the two equations yields
$$u(f,\mathcal{R})-l(f,\mathcal{R})=\sum_{i=0}^n H_i(r_{i+1})(r_{i+1}-r_i)-\sum_{i=0}^n h_i(r_{i+1})(r_{i+1}-r_i)=\sum_{i=0}^n(H_i(r_{i+1})-h_i(r_{i+1}))(r_{i+1}-r_i).$$ 
Using the property that our partition has gives us 
$$u(f,\mathcal{R})-l(f,\mathcal{R})<\sum_{i=0}^n\epsilon_I(r_{i+1}-r_i)=\epsilon_I\sum_{i=0}^n(r_{i+1}-r_i)=\epsilon_I(b-a).$$
Hence, the difference between $u(f,\mathcal{R})$ and $l(f,\mathcal{R})$ can become arbitrarily small.

Theorem 1: If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b],$ then $\int_a^b f$ is defined. 
Proof: We already know that $L_a^b(f) \le U_a^b(f)$ since it is property 3 (and I have proven it earlier). To eliminate one of the remaining two cases, assume that 
$$L_a^b(f)<U_a^b(f).$$
By definition, 
$$u(f,\mathcal{R})\ge U_a^b(f),$$
$$l(f,\mathcal{R})\le L_a^b(f).$$
Consequently, 
$$l(f,\mathcal{R})\le L_a^b(f)<U_a^b(f)\le u(f,\mathcal{R}).$$
Rearranging yields 
$$0\le L_a^b(f)-l(f,\mathcal{R})<U_a^b(f)-l(f,\mathcal{R})\le u(f,\mathcal{R})-l(f,\mathcal{R}).$$
Therefore, 
$$0<U_a^b(f)-l(f,\mathcal{R})\le u(f,\mathcal{R})-l(f,\mathcal{R}).$$
This implies that there exists a $0<d<U_a^b(f)-l(f,\mathcal{R})$ such that 
$$u(f,\mathcal{R})-l(f,\mathcal{R})>d.$$
This is a contradiction. Thus, for any continuous function $f$ defined on $[a,b],$ it must be the case that
$$L_a^b(f)=U_a^f(f).$$
This means that 
$$\int_a^b f=L_a^b(f)=U_a^b(f)$$
is defined as desired.
$\square$

Comment: Well, as soon as one $\delta$ works, so do all smaller positive numbers.

Comment: Yeah, so it is essentially the set of $\delta$'s less than $\sup\{\Delta_{\epsilon_I}\}$ and greater than zero. Does it have a name though? Should I post the proof in which I used it here?

Comment: I would be very interested in any proof which needs this specific set. Please edit your question to include this proof.

Comment: I added the proof in which I used it. I didn't know uniform continuity at the time (and I still don't) but I wanted to figure it out on my own. Note that corollary 1/2 and lemma 1/2 are very similar statements. Either lemma 1 or 2 should give you the gist of the proof for the first two corollaries.

Comment: In topology and real analysis, $U_{\epsilon}(x)$ is sometimes used to denote the set of elements $y$ satisfying $|y - x| < \epsilon$, and $f^{-1}(U_{\epsilon})$ would be used to denote the set of elements $z$ such that $f(z) \in U_{\epsilon}$.  This is related to (but not of course not the same) as the set you describe.

Comment: One nice consequence of the definition I've given is that we can say that a function $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U_{\epsilon}(x))$ is open for every $x$ in the domain and every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful. It'll be a while till I start topology though! Is there a name for the set you describe?

Comment: Omnomnomnom's set $U_\epsilon(x)$ is commonly called the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ about $x$. I would say it is more common now to see it called $B(x, \epsilon)$ or $B_\epsilon(x)$, but certainly the $U$ notation is often used. $f^{-1}(U)$ is called the inverse image of $U$ under $f$, for any set $U$. Things generally get names that become convention only when a shorthand way of refering to them is useful to a wide swath of the community, so that people have reason to recall the name and use it themselves. Inverse images of balls is too specific an application for this to be true, IMO.